# JSDoc, referring to identifiers in a function description

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there a way to emphasize an identifier in a function description?
For example, in this simplified snippet:

```
function a () {
  var page;
  ...
  /**
   * Reads data from page starting with line.
   * @param {number} line
   */
  function readSomething (line) {
    ...
  }
}
```

it seems that it would be great to distinguish between the parameter name, the outer variable name and other words, just looking at the description.

Of course, in real code identifiers are more self-descriptive and they can relatively easy be recognized if they're written in camel case or snake case, but it is still an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mark them up yourself. The basic way to do this is to use HTML markup: `<code>page</code>`

If you are using jsdoc 3.x, it is also possible to turn on the Markdown plugin and use Markdown markup `` `page` ``.